# jsonapi-resources custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2, jsonapi-resources

I need to add a custom action to my jsonapi-resources controller. This action just creates e new version of a preexistent CollectorContent model instance. My implementation (just copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132012/how-to-render-a-jsonapi-resources-response-in-an-custom-controller-action)):

**routes.rb**

```
jsonapi_resources :collector_contents do
  member do
    post :create_version
  end
end
```

**collector_contents_controller.rb**

```
class CollectorContentsController < ApplicationController
  def create_version
    cc = CollectorContent.find(params[:id])
    cc_new_version = cc.create_version!
    render json: resource_serializer.serialize_to_hash(CollectorContentResource.new(cc_new_version, nil))
  end
end
```

Even if it works it seems that adding a new action in the controller [is not the recommended way](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources/issues/921) but I don't understand how I can use a *operation processor* to implement my use case. Can you help please?